# Generating an array of random points in java with no duplicates

Tags: java, random

I am fairly new to Java, and I want to generate an array of random (x,y) coordinates of length 'number' that contains no duplicates. x or y values can be repeated, but there must be no repeated (x,y) coordinates. The output does not have to be Points, simply some way of holding x,y values for coordinates.

I can generate an array of random points, and have tried using a Set to ensure there are no duplicate values, but have run into problems. I tried using the condition "while (set.size)" and the 'add' method which should disallow duplicates, to create an output of the correct size which contains unique points.

This is the code:

```
Set<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
Random position = new Random();
Point test=new Point();

do{
    test.x=position.nextInt(xx);
    test.y=position.nextInt(yy);   
    //xx and yy are the random number limits called from another part of the code
    set.add(test);     
}
while (set.size()<number);

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
Object[] coord = list.toArray();
```

This outputs an array of the correct length, but every element is the same. Can anyone offer any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

test points to the same variable in space everytime you loop, to fix that create a new instance inside the loop - not just once before it:

```
Set<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
Random position = new Random();
Point test;

do{
    test = new Point();
    test.x=position.nextInt(xx);
    test.y=position.nextInt(yy);   
    //xx and yy are the random number limits called from another part of the code
    set.add(test);     
}
while (set.size()<number);

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
Object[] coord = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the same point object. However, since you change X and Y every time, you also changing hash code and equality of the point, so you end up placing the same object multiple times in the set. Interesting case.

try

```
do{
   test = new Point();
   test.x=position.nextInt(xx);
   test.y=position.nextInt(yy);   
   //xx and yy are the random number limits called from another part of the code
   set.add(test);     
}
while (set.size()<number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Value select Randomly but not repeated

```
    Random rndm = new Random();
    String[] selectedNumber = new String[15];
    String[] sequanceNumber = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"};

    //*****FIRST LOOP START*****//
    for(byte a = 0; a < 15;){

        int temp = rndm.nextInt(15)+1;

        //*****SECOND LOOP START*****//
        for(byte b = 0; b < 15; b++){

            String s4 = temp+"";

            //*****CHECKING CONDITION START*****//
            if(s4.equals(sequanceNumber[b]) ){


                selectedNumber[a] = s4;

                String s1 = sequanceNumber[b];
                s1 = s1.replace(s1, " ");
                sequanceNumber[b] = s1;

                a++;

            }
            //*****CHECKING CONDITION END*****//
        }
        //*****SECOND LOOP END*****//
    }
    //*****FIRST LOOP END*****//


    //*****PRINT ALL RANDOM VALUES BUT NOT REPEATED VALUES*****//
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectedNumber));
```